# how to differentiate click and press on UIButton iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have one button which i am using to record video and take photo from camera.

On click i want to take picture and on press start video recording.

```
      [self.recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(recordTouchCancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];
  [self.recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(recordTouchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  [self.recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(recordTouchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(recordTouchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

Press to record is working perfect but not able to get click, how can i differentiate click and hold on UIButton.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might looking for `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. I notice that the API automatically trigger the right event between the tap and long press.

**Take a look at Apple doc about** 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html

**There is an exemple**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // FRIST SET TARGET & SELECTOR TO BUTTON
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer * pressLong =  [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(takeVideo:)];
    [self.recordButton addGestureRecognizer:pressLong];
    [self.recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(takePicture:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}


-(void)takePicture:(UIButton*) sender {
    // TAKE PIC
}


-(void)takeVideo : (UILongPressGestureRecognizer*) gesture   {

    NSInteger state = gesture.state;

    switch (state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
             //START RECORD
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
             //END RECORD
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

"UIControlEventTouchDown" and "UIControlEventTouchUpInside" are 2 different state.  when you start to tab button "UIControlEventTouchDown" is called and when you give you finger "UIControlEventTouchUpInside" is called.and time between start and end of your tap there is no other state. So you can't do by this way.

But you can try "UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat" state. this is called when user tap twice on a button.

In you situation it better to use "tapGuesture"